# What areas/topics should one invest in learning/training?

Tags: administration, future

I was granted/offered by our CEO that I can take a course (or other training on salesforce).

This got me to think: WOW - there are so many fields/areas/topics in Salesforce, and as my knowledge as CIO - is pretty much an above the radar knowledge (I know enough to run our operations). I was wondering: what should I ask/invest in?

I understand this can be considered as a very subjective Q&A, so what I am looking for is:

- What are the areas/topics that you think One should invest in?
- What is the future of SalesForce as you see it, and what areas/topics will be the BUZZ words in the future?

If considering a fresh starter: **What will you suggest to one to learn?**

can anyone suggest/think of such?

Comment: Stack exchange discourages such discussion type questions since this is NOT a discussion forum but a question answer site. You should aim to ask questions that will lead to a concrete answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is Saalesforce's Annual Event i.e. DreamForce.
This is the event for all types of audiences with lots of awesome sessions. You may love to have a look on this : [Dreamforce DF12](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF12/)

Next Steps I would suggest is to  :

1. Explore the Force.com Platform [Force.com](http://www.force.com/)
2. Understand Sales Cloud and Service Cloud offerings from Salesforce
3. The most important weblink that I visit everyday is Developer Force Link [Developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com/)

Hope I have tried to answer your question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I'll second the suggestion of Dreamforce; that's probably the best way to get a good overview of the platform, its capabilities and the upcoming roadmap.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions. Dreamforce is not an option this year. However, I am planning to take a SF administrator training. thanks